# Android Smack MessageEventManager not compiling

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am using smack API with openfire server to make an android app. I am trying to implement a MessageEventManager and MessageEventProvider to my app so it will tell me if the message was delivered or not though when i try to declare it a MessageEventManager, it is not compiling and tells me to create that class, What can i do? i have the following dependencies in my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
}
```

Do i need an extra for it? I would appreciate any help Thanks.

IMG:

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you post the Log? the text of the error as it comes out?

Comment: @TommySM it doesnt come out an error but when i declare it in my file it doesn't tell me import class it just says create class, i have attached an image.

Comment: @TommySM could you help me on this question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107005/android-smack-4-1-1-file-transfering-error-could-not-establish-socket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I might be wrong, but it seems it's not included in Smack4.1, I can't tell if it's deprecated or not since I haven't seen it on the deprecated lists, and the documentation exists [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/xevent/MessageEventManager.html) and [here for the parent class](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Manager.html).

But... what I did find is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241444/android-smack-messageeventlistener) by the Author of Smack, that clearly states that

> Message events in SMACK are done via the now obsolete XEP-22. There is a good chance that the other side does not implement this out-dated mechanism.

Since this is dated 3 years back, it might be a good idea to look for another solution, or (depending on your needs, might not be recommended) use an older version Smack or aSmack.

Comment: Yeah i was doing my research yesterday and i read that too. I was wondering if theres a way to see if the message was delivered to the server or not. Is it a good idea to do it with DeliveryReceiptManager?

Comment: I have less experience with that one but by a quick look at the Docs it looks exactly like what you need, I say go for it.

Comment: thanks, for your help bro i already did that but i thought there was an easy way lol but dont worry we are developers xd we have to find out a way to do what ever we need or want :p thanks again.

 Tom i dont know if you can send me a private message in here otherwise how can i add you? XD

Comment: Well I'm here almost everyday, you could always use the chat through meta :)

Answer (score 2):

Message event manager (XEP-22) are obsolete now, but smack team still maintain it. You can use smack legacy library throgh gradle

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-legacy:4.1.3"
```